# How can I fetch one specific data's detail from MySQL by using Axios or other function in React?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm figuring out how to fetch one specific data's detail from the MySQL database.
I'm not good ad English, but I will try to explain what the response that I want looks like.

I'll show my code down below!!

This is my server `index.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  user: 'root',
  host: 'localhost',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'root',
});

/* GET */
app.get('/cows', (req, res) => {
  const sqlSelect =
    'SELECT cid, cname, cname_eng, c_img, tname FROM type t LEFT JOIN cow c ON c.c_type1 = t.tid ORDER BY cid';
  db.query(sqlSelect, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      // res.send("Success");
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});

app.get('/cows_detail/:name', (req, res) => {
  const engName = req.body.name;
  const sqlSelect =
    'SELECT c.cid, c.cname, cname_eng, tname, c.rune1, c.rune2, c.c_eq, c.su_skill, c.c_img FROM type t LEFT JOIN cow c ON c.c_type1 = t.tid WHERE cname_eng = ? ORDER BY cid';
  db.query(sqlSelect, [engName], (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      // res.send("Success");
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('Your server is start running on port 4000');
});
```

And in React frontend, this is my `CowsDetail.js`

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams, useHistory, Route, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import Axios from 'axios';

const CowsDetail = ({ match }) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { name } = useParams();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDetail();
  }, []);

  const fetchDetail = async () => {
    const result = await Axios.get(
      `http://localhost:4000/cows_detail/${match.params.name}`
    ).catch((err) => console.log('Error:', err));

    if (result && result.data) setCowDetails(result.data);

    console.log('result', result.data); //console: []
    console.log('match name', match.params.name); // examples: Jerry
    console.log('match', match); 
//isExact: true
//params: {name: "Jerry"}
//path: "/cows_detail/:name"
//url: "/cows_detail/Jerry"
//__proto__: Object


  const [cowDetails, setCowDetails] = useState({});

  const handleBackClick = () => {
    history.goBack();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Cow {name}'s Detail Pages</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          handleBackClick();
        }}
      >
        Back to the Cow Page
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CowsDetail;
```

And here is the questions,
I have a component `<Cow />` which URL is `localhost:3000/cow`, and when
I click one of it(for example: `<Cow name='Jerry'/>`),
I want the path link to => `localhost:3000/cow_detail/Jerry`
and show more `Cow` Jerry's Detail.

What can I do when I just want to only take `Jerry` details??

Hope I didn't make this question more complicated, thank you, guys!!

Comment: you want on click change route and show details of "Cow"?

Comment: @BogdanPryvalov Yes sir!!!